# System UI crashes when using setRequestedOrientation when Screen orientation is locked

Tags: android, android-fragments, crash

I am trying to force the App into Landscape by using

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_LANDSCAPE);
```

in onResume in a Fragment and set it again to

```
SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED
```

in onPause so it is only in landscape for this fragment.

This works fine when screen orientation is not locked. But as soon as i lock the screen orientation in android the whole device crashes.

I have testet it with differenet devices and found that it works fine even if orientation is locked on a Nexus 6.

But on my Galaxy S8 it completly crashed.
Also on xiaomi mi mix it the App crashed but the device didn't.

Does anyone know a way around this?

This is what my phone looks like after a few seconds.

[image: Crash]